# Create more specific x-labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
 ikr <- read.csv2("eucaris_trend.csv", header = T)
 head(ikr)

 YEAR Eucaris Niet.Eucaris
 1    8   81867    0.1527756
 2    9   91507    0.1533734
 3   10  102755    0.1733875
 4   11  116491    0.1648633
 5   12   55133    0.1771800
 6   13   67115    0.1449571
```

Of this data I want to create the following graph:

```
 graph <- ggplot(ikr, aes(x = YEAR, y=Eucaris)) + geom_line(linetype="dashed", size=1, colour="blue") + geom_point(size=4, shape=22, colour="darkred", fill="pink")
```

Works fine but im not happy with x labels. I want to say 8,9,10,11 etc.. instead of 8,10 etc.. I tried changing the x-labels doing this:

```
graph2 <- graph + scale_x_discrete(labels=c(8,9,10,11,12...))
```

but then my graph looks really weird. Any thought on how I can easily change the xlabels?

Comment: `breaks = c(8,9,10,11,12...)` maybe

Comment: Ditto @baptiste; it's probably defaulting to this given the size of the plotting window; specify the breaks per above, and/or enlarge your plot window/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine:

```
df <- read.table(text ="YEAR Eucaris Niet.Eucaris
1    8   81867    0.1527756
2    9   91507    0.1533734
3   10  102755    0.1733875
4   11  116491    0.1648633
5   12   55133    0.1771800
6   13   67115    0.1449571", header =TRUE)

library(scales) # For formatting y-axis    
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x = YEAR, y=Eucaris)) + 
          geom_line(linetype="dashed", size=1, colour="blue") + 
          geom_point(size=4, shape=22, colour="darkred", fill="pink")+
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment. When I try reading in the file using read.table instead of read.csv it works fine. Only one small thingie. Do you know how I can show the proper Y values (81867  in stead of 8e+04) @mpalanco

Comment: @Marc van der Peet I edited the answer to format the y-axis

Comment: Hi @Marc van der Peet if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.